# Could not insert module, no space left on device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel-module

Currently, I'am trying to debug the cfq-scheduler by copying the scheduler from linux/block/cfq-iosched.c and all the necessary header files, and make them into a custom kernel-module.

I don't need the cfq's default debugging properties because there is something else I needed to test it.

I have successfully build the cfq-iosched into ko file and trying to install it by using

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sungho sungho  741872 Jul  8 14:36 cfq-iosched.ko    
insmod cfq-iosched.ko
```

However I am getting the error:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module cfq-iosched.ko: No space left on device
```

At first, I thought it was due to low disk space, but it should be unlikely given my available disk-size of 17.7GB.

I need a way to install the cfq scheduler as a custom module. I need to do this in order to thoroughly check the mechanism of cfq scheduler.

Comment: Error code you get is `-ENOSPC`. You might check sources and try to guess where it comes from. There might be different reasons why you got it, e.g. there is no room in an internal structure in kernel for such scheduler.

Comment: @0andriy But How do I know there is no room in an internal structure?

Comment: Read my first comment again carefully follow by reading sources.

Comment: I guess `-ENOSPC` is returned by [blkcg_policy_register](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/block/blk-cgroup.c#L1404) function because there are only 3 slots for "policies", and all of them are already in use.